# How do I logout of the github website?

Tags: github

This sounds like a ridiculous question, but how do I logout of the github website?

Other than deleting a cookie.

Comment: https://github.com/logout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a little door icon on the right side of the menu bar that points to https://github.com/logout

Comment: @M3NTA7: It'd be nice if GitHub included some text as well. I don't like the icons very much.

Comment: It's actually pretty funny that I didn't see it, I was hovering over the other two icons and just ignored that one.

Comment: I don't even see the door icon, as of today.  Had to manually navigate to https://github.com/logout.

Comment: @AndyDennie: The links are still there, but all of the icons are missing. That's really odd.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the door that has an arrow coming out from it. It is on the top right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IE Browser does not show the logout graphic but the HOVER TEXT that says LOGOUT is there.  Try moving your mouse on the top menu bar across the top where you see nothing and you will see the logout hover text show up.    
  IE does not do the BUTTON element the same as other browsers.